# How to use `PublishSingleFile` option for `dotnet` and macOS?

Tags: c#, linux, macos, .net-core

I use `dotnet` on macOS and want to build an application for Linux. To achive this, I use the following commands:

```
dotnet --version #
3.0.101

dotnet new console -n HelloWorld

dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -o ./linux-publish
```

According to [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/) article, the `dotnet` command should support a command-line flag to pack the application into a single executable:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Why is there no `PublishSingleFile` option for `dotnet` on macOS?
2. Why does `dotnet` both create a HelloWorld executable and a HelloWorld.dll?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Re: Why is there no `PublishSingleFile` option for dotnet on macOS?

There is, at least in version **[`3.1.100`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-3.1.100-macos-x64-installer)**, so maybe try updating.

> Why does `dotnet` both create a HelloWorld executable and a
>   HelloWorld.dll?

The important concepts here are that of a portable app (which is what you get by default) and self-contained apps (in which a single executable file is produced).

A portable app is an application that runs independently of the platform and requires that the `.NET` shared framework is installed. When published, the shared framework is not copied to the `publish` folder — including the native host. In order to run it, `dotnet <path_to_your_dll>` would be invoked. dotnet in this case is the native piece, the host (which isn't what you are wanting here).

For self-contained apps, an `RID` needs to be specified (which you have done correctly in your example). I'm thinking that the main reason you might be having an issue with things not working correctly is that you are running an older version of the `SDK`, so I would recommend updating to the current release version.

When you invoke the `dotnet publish` command it should end up being similar to the following:

```
$ dotnet publish -r osx.10.13-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 39.77 ms for /usr/local/share/dotnet/myApp/myApp.csproj.
  myApp -> /usr/local/share/dotnet/myApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/osx.10.13-x64/myApp.dll
  myApp -> /usr/local/share/dotnet/myApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/osx.10.13-x64/publish/
```

*(I use `osx.10.13-x64` because that's what shows with the output of this command):*

```
$ dotnet --info

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  65f04fb6db

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

In file `myApp.csproj` include the `RID`(s) aka `RunTimeIndentifers` you are building against:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>osx.10.13-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Now back to the matter at hand regarding the two directories resulting from the `publish` command. The `myApp.dll` directory is essentially all of the parts that make up your application.

It can be executed by the following:

```
$ cd /usr/local/share/dotnet/myApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/osx.10.13-x64
$ ls
(tons of files which comprise the app)
$ dotnet myApp.dll
Hello World!
```

However, you want the *single file* of all that junk, the standalone executable file located in `publish`:

```
$ cd /usr/local/share/dotnet/myApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/osx.10.13-x64/publish/
$ ls
myApp     myApp.pdb
$ ./myApp
Hello World!
```

There's a lengthy discussion linked below if you want further insight:

↳ https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6237

This official tutorial might also be helpful:

↳ https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro?sdk-installed=true

Comment: Good answer. I find [this article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx) to be helpful as well

Comment: You are right, `/p:PublishSingleFile=true` is supported on macOS. I find it odd thus, that nothing is mentioned of a `/p` option in the `dotnet publish --help` text?

Comment: @Shuzheng: It's a mystery to me why `/p` isn't mentioned, and I agree, there are many details that should be explained better. Hopefully my answer helped you somewhat; if you continue having issues let me know.

Comment: Also, why is you `dotnet publish -r osx.10.13-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true` command above producing a `myApp.dll`, when it's instructed to create a single-file output for the given runtime?

Comment: It seems that adding `<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` to .csproj doesn't matter when running `dotnet publish` - at least not in my case when targeting `linux-x64`? In either case, I need to provide the runtime to `dotnet` as an `-r, --runtime` argument.

Comment: @Shuzheng: When you run `dotnet publish` it creates a directory with all the dependencies in it (including the `.dll`). The command appears to take all of those items and then create the `publish` directory and all of those items compiled into a single file within that directory. It's obviously confusing, but think of it as a temporary build directory of sorts which doesn't get cleaned up for whatever reason.

Comment: @Shuzheng: Check [this `json` file](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json), it has all of the current possible runtimes available. So for the `linux-x64` you might want to try `arch-x64` instead, since that is the parent name.

Comment: Can you confirm that `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` in .csproj has no effect on `dotnet publish`? Is `dotnet` part of the .NET shared framework?

Comment: @Shuzheng: When using `dotnet publish -r linux-x64`, etc. I did not need to include `RuntimeIdentifiers` within `.csproj`. The singlefile that I just built on `macOS` comes back with `myApp: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped`. So it appears that it works; I would imagine that it's possible to statically link it as well, but haven't actually tried it.